# Invalid identifier with CAST

Tags: sql, oracle, casting, average, alias

My table in Oracle DB 12.1.0 contains Timestamp and Value. Values are gathered every 1 second. I need to keep only 1-minute average.
For example

```
datetime    value
01.11.2013 0:00:01  10
01.11.2013 0:00:02  20
01.11.2013 0:00:03  10
01.11.2013 0:00:04  20
...
01.11.2013 0:00:59  10
```

Should return

```
dt  average
01.11.2013 0:00:00  14,91525424
01.11.2013 0:01:00  ...
```

I try to truncate by minute and calculate average. It works without dt alias.

```
select cast(trunc(datetime,'mi') as timestamp) dt, avg(value) as average
from my_table
group by dt order by dt
```

But got ORA-00904: "DT": invalid identifier error. I need an alias to insert the result into a new table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot use aliases for grouping , use like this :

```
select cast(trunc(datetime,'mi') as timestamp) dt, avg(value) as average
from my_table
group by cast(trunc(datetime,'mi') as timestamp) 
order by cast(trunc(datetime,'mi') as timestamp);
```

Comment: Wow, that's all. Error position was referring to the first mentioning of dt (cast(trunc(datetime,'mi') as timestamp) dt) so I tried a lot of different combinations, but didn't check yours. Thank you a lot! Tesekkurler :)

Comment: @KirillDrozdov pojalusta :)

Answer (score 0):

The `cast` isn't really the problem; you can't use a column expression alias in the same level of query, except in the order-by clause. That's because of the order the statement is parsed and executed. [From the docs](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/sqlrf/SELECT.html):

> **c_alias**
>
> Specify an alias for the column expression. Oracle Database will use this alias in the column heading of the result set. The `AS` keyword is optional. The alias effectively renames the select list item for the duration of the query. The alias can be used in the *order_by_clause* but not other clauses in the query.

You can use a subquery, or in this case just repeat the expression; you don't even need to include the cast:

```
select cast(trunc(datetime,'mi') as timestamp) dt, avg(value) as average
from my_table
group by trunc(datetime,'mi')
order by dt
/
```

If you really want to use the alias in the group-by` clause still - maybe your real expression is much more complicated - you need to use an inline view or CTE:

```
select dt, avg(value) as average
from (
  select cast(trunc(datetime,'mi') as timestamp) dt, value
  from my_table
)
group by dt
order by dt;
```